# Tcolorbox: fit does not strictly start at the top

Tags: tcolorbox, fit

I don't know why, but when I use the `fit` option in tcolorbox, the fit is a bit "too high", and above the other text by a few px. Any idea why?

Thanks!

[image]

Zoom:

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % To switch to the T1 encoding
\usepackage{lmodern} % To switch to Latin Modern
\usepackage{exscale}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, amsmath}
% \usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{palatino}

\usepackage[a0paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[poster,most]{tcolorbox}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
    coverage = {
      spread,
      % interior style={top color=yellow,bottom color=yellow!50!red},
      top=25mm, bottom=25mm, left=15mm, right=15mm,
    },
    poster   = {showframe=false,columns=4,rows=5,spacing=13mm},
    boxes    = {
      enhanced standard jigsaw,sharp corners=downhill,
      arc=10mm, boxrule=2mm,
      coltitle=black!85,
      boxsep=0pt,
      top=15mm,bottom=15mm,right=15mm,left=15mm,
      colback=white,opacityback=0.75,colframe=cyan!30!white!90!black,
      title style={left color=cyan!20!white!90!black,
        right color=cyan!20!white!90!black,
      },
      fonttitle=\Large\scshape\bfseries,
      valign=center,
    },
    fontsize = 36pt
    ]

  \posterbox[blankest,interior engine=path,height=10cm,
    halign=center,valign=center,colupper=black,
    ]{name=title,column=1,span=4,below=top}{
    {\Huge\bf\textsc{Here is\\[.3em]
        My Title}}\\[.3em]
    \textsc{Here are Some Names}
  }

  % \posterbox[adjusted title=Maximum space,valign=top]
  % {name=security,below=title,column=1,span=1,rowspan=1}{%
  %   \rule{\textwidth}{\tcbtextheight}
  % }

  \posterbox[adjusted title=Top,valign=top]
  {name=security,below=title,column=2,span=.5,rowspan=1}{%
    Hello
  }

  \posterbox[adjusted title=Bot,valign=bottom]
  {name=security,below=title,column*=2,span=.5,rowspan=1}{%
    Hello
  }

  \posterbox[adjusted title=No fit,valign=top]
  {name=security,below=title,column=3,span=1,rowspan=1}{%
    Hello world, how are you my dear? Hello world, how are you my dear? Hello world, how are you my dear? Hello world, how are you my dear? Hello world, how are you my dear? Hello world, how are you my dear? Hello world, how are you my dear? Hello world, how are you my dear? Hello world, how are you my dear?
  }

  \posterbox[adjusted title=Fit,valign=top,fit]
  {name=security,below=title,column=4,span=1,rowspan=1}{%
    Hello world, how are you my dear? Hello world, how are you my dear? Hello world, how are you my dear? Hello world, how are you my dear? Hello world, how are you my dear? Hello world, how are you my dear? Hello world, how are you my dear? Hello world, how are you my dear? Hello world, how are you my dear? Hello
  }

\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have forgetten `fit` parameter in `posterbox` column 3. `\posterbox[adjusted title=No fit,valign=top,fit]`

Comment: @ferahfeza not really, this is just to show how it looks like with no fit. The problem is actually column 4 that is 1-2px to high.

Comment: I just compiled your document twice and I don't have this problem. Have you compiled twice?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because seems to solved by comments.